# Is it possible to put an assignment into a context, so that the variable is not available after the block?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider this:

```
mydict['a'].f()
mydict['a'].g()
```

This repeats `mydict['a']` undesirably. One option might be:

```
a = mydict['a']
a.f()
a.g()
# but now `a` pollutes the scope
```

So we could modify this to:

```
a = mydict['a']
a.f()
a.g()
del a
```

However, I find this a little displeasing, though I am not sure why.

Maybe we could wrap this in a function?

```
def do_things(a):
    a.f()
    a.g()
do_things(mydict['a'])
```

I don't think this is much better. And now we also have an unnecessary function in the scope, not to mention function calling overhead.

What I really want is something like:

```
with a = mydict['a']:
    a.f()
    a.g()
# there is no `a` here
```

Is this possible?

Comment: For what it's worth, `scapy` uses the `del` approach. They have some top-level for-loops in the module that run on import and they `del` the loop variable after to avoid pollution.

Comment: Outside of a function returning, the only way a variable is automatically deleted is when it is used to capture an exception in an `except` clause.

Comment: So sounds impossible. Would it be worth suggesting to python dev team?

Answer (score 2):

There are (to my knowledge) only two ways a variable is automatically deleted:

1. When it goes out of scope
2. After the completion of an `except ... as ...` clause that bound the variable to an exception.

I wouldn't worry unduly about polluting the namespace. You can do something *similar* to your `with` statement example using a `nullcontext` context manager from `contextlib`:

```
from contextlib import nullcontext


with nullcontext(mydict['a']) as a:
    a.f()
    a.g()
```

(which is just a very verbose way of allowing your use of `a` to be indented under its assignment, creating a visual indication of where `a`
is intended to be used).

`a` remains bound to your dict, but the same type of thing happens anytime you write

```
with open(...) as f:
    ...
```

The file-like object remains bound to `f`. Unless it *matters* that your `dict` now has a higher reference count, there's no great need to immediately delete the name. If the name stays in scope for a long time, that is perhaps a sign that you should refactor your code anyway.